# Pass Class to Generic Method Which Execute Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql, linq, generics

Here is my database structure:

[image]

I am using Linq-to-SQL, here is my class structure.

```
 DataBaseClassDataContext context = new DataBaseClassDataContext();
 GenericMethod gm = new GenericMethod();
 var student= gm.GetData<info>(1);
 var info = gm.GetData<Student>(2);
 Console.ReadLine();
```

Here is my `GenericMethod` class:

```
DataBaseClassDataContext context = new DataBaseClassDataContext();

public List<T> GetData<T>(int classcode) 
{
    if (classcode == 1)
    {
         return context.InfoSelect().Cast<T>().ToList<T>();
    }
    else
    {
        return context.StudentSelect().Cast<T>().ToList<T>();
    }
}
```

I want to pass class to my generic method, which further run stored procedure and give back me list of that class. How can I do that? I get an error

> Unable to cast object of type 'GenericMethods.StudentSelectResult' to type 'GenericMethods.Student'.

Kindly guide me, what am I missing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899629/cast-object-to-t - does it help?

Comment: @KokaChernov..I insert following line `return (T)Convert.ChangeType(context.StudentSelect().Cast<T>().ToList<T>(), typeof(T));`,it gives error Cannot implicitly convert type 'T' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>'

Comment: Run this: var type= context.StudentSelect().First().GetType(); Tell us what "type" is.

Comment: Or try smth like `(T)Convert.ChangeType(context.StudentSelect().First(), typeof(T));`

Comment: @GeorgeVovos...now type contains a number of properties...tell me what exactly you want from these properties

Comment: @KokaChernov..same error

Comment: @MuhammadAli type.FullName

Comment: type.FullName =GenericMethods.StudentSelectResult

Comment: by changing this line `var student= gm.GetData<InfoSelectResult>(1);`,i got result...:)

Comment: @MuhammadAli you've got the result of the other type, not `Student`?

Comment: @KokaChernov..it is the sp class in .dbml class,that returns me the sp result