# How to cast object to Anonymous T

Tags: c#, object, dynamic, casting, ienumerable

I'm having a problem casting with C#

First, my auxiliary functions for better understanding

```
public static class Extensions {
    public static IEnumerable<T> ToEnumerable<T>(this T value) {
        yield return value;
    }
    public static dynamic ToDynamic(this object value) {
        IDictionary<string, object> e = new ExpandoObject(); 
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor item in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(value.GetType())) { e.Add(item.Name, item.GetValue(value));
        return e;
    }
    public static IEnumerable<T> ToCast<T>(this IEnumerable<object> value, T sample) where T: class {
        return null; /* HELP */
    }
    public static T ToCastFirstorDefault<T>(this object value, T sample) where T: class {
        return value.ToEnumerable().ToCast(sample).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

On the controller side there is an object data as seen in the example

```
object Model = new { take = 10, data = new object[] { new { tarih = DateTime.MaxValue, proje = "Lorem Ipsum", durum = true } } };
```

I can use it in .cshtml page side by using ToDynamic, ToEnumerable functions

```
var dy = Model.ToEnumerable().Select(x => x.ToDynamic()).Select(x => new
    {
        take = (int)x.take,
        data = ((object[])x.data).Select(y => y.ToDynamic()).Select(y => new
        {
            tarih = (DateTime)y.tarih,
            proje = (string)y.proje,
            durum = (bool)y.durum
        })
    }).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Although this build works 100% correctly, not user-friendly at all when there are more properties

I want so that I can use the ToCast, ToCastFirstorDefault functions as I wrote in the example below.
Is it possible?

```
var rslt = Model.ToCastFirstorDefault(new {
    take = 0,
    data  = default(object[])
});
```

Or:

```
var rslt = Model.ToCastFirstorDefault(new {
    take = 0,
    data  = default(object[])
}).ToEnumerable().Select(x=> new {
    x.take,
    data = x.data.ToCast(new { tarih = default(DateTime), proje = "", durum = false })
}).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

I couldn't use Convert.ChangeType because of the anonymous type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cast object to T](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899629/cast-object-to-t)

Comment: @YungDeiza Anonymous types are not IConvertible. I looked at the related article before posting.

Comment: Sorry, how about this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1409776/19214431?

Comment: @YungDeiza 
before i tried its structure CastTo<T> functions. result exception: f_Anonymous143'1[System.Object[]] not convert f_Anonymous0'1[System.Object[]]